# Error reading .jar; error in opening zip file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jni

Eu tenho uma aplicação Java desktop que usa o JasperReport para geração de relatórios, a aplicação executa normalmente em minha maquina, mas na maquina de meu cliente a mesma não executa. Abaixo está a Stack Trace quando a aplicação executa na maquina de meu cliente. Alguém tem idéia do porque a aplicação não conseguir abrir os jars necessários para o jasper funcionar?

```
Created dir: C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 55 source files to C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\build\classes
error: error reading C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\lib\iText-2.1.7.js2.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\lib\jasperreports-5.6.1.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\lib\jasperreports-applet-5.6.1.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\lib\jasperreports-fonts-5.6.1.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\lib\jasp    erreports-javaflow-5.6.1.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\lib\jcommon-1.0.15.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\lib\jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\lib\jfreechart-1.0.12.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\lib\png-encoder-1.5.jar; error in opening zip file
9 errors
C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:929: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\PC4ADMINISTRADOR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignusSystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:269: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 3 segundos)
```

Arquivo build-impl.xml line 929:

```
928 <target depends="init,deps-jar,-pre-pre-compile,-pre-compile, -copy-persistence-xml,-compile-depend" if="have.sources" name="-do-compile">
929  <j2seproject3:javac gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
930     <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}">
931         <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="${build.classes.excludes},${excludes}" includes="${includes}"/>
932     </copy>
933 </target>
```

Arquivo build.impl.xml line 269

```
<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
```

Comment: Tem mais algum erro ou o erro é somente esta linha? Seu aplicativo é desktop certo?

Comment: Em seguida é mostrado essa mensagem de erro: "A Java Exception Has occurred". É uma aplicação desktop, o estranho é que se eu retirar os importes para as classes do Jasper, a aplicação funciona normalmente. Mas se tento usar o jasper, a aplicação não funciona.

Comment: Adicionei a StackTrace do erro, mas ainda não tenho idéia do porque da aplicação não conseguir abri os .jars

Comment: Ele está dando erro a ler os seus jars. Normalmente uso Maven para resolver este tipo de problema. Tentaria recriar a pasta e baixar novamente os jars adicionando-os ao classpath via IDE.